# mostrar id´s en un select en ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy trabajando con dos *scaffolds* en *rails*, uno llamado contactos y otro negociaciones. Hay una relación de uno a muchos (un contacto puede tener muchas negociaciones).

En el *scaffold* de negociaciones, tengo un campo que se llama `identificación`, en el que cuando le pongo un `id` (en número) del contacto, me muestra todos los datos que deseo del contacto. Pero quiero poner también una venta desplegable, es decir, un `select`, para que me muestre la lista de todos los `id`'s de los nuevos contactos que vaya creando, para así no tener que memorizar que `id` tiene el último contacto que he creado, sino seleccionarlo directamente de mi `select`. Y he hecho algo así:

```
<%= form.select :contacto_id, <aqui me falta algo>, id: :negociacion_contacto_id%>
```

Donde pongo `<aqui me falta algo>` he probado con `contactos_id.all`, pero me da error. ¿Alguien me puede por favor indicar que debería introducir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas un arreglo bidimensional donde indiques el valor a mostrar en el select y el valor de la opción seleccionada.

Por ejemplo, suponiendo que en tu modelo `Contacto` tengas un atributo llamado `nombre` y otro llamado `id`, entonces podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
Contacto.pluck(:nombre, :id)
#=> [["User870701", 1], ["Gerry", 2]]
```

Este código lo puedes utilizar en el `form.select` para proporcionar el arreglo que requiere el *helper*:

```
<%= form.select :contacto_id, Contacto.pluck(:nombre, :id), id: :negociacion_contacto_id %>
```

Lo que generaría un código *html* similar al siguiente fragmento:

```
<select name="contacto_id" id="negociacion_contacto_id">
  <option value="1">User870701</option>
  <option value="2">Gerry</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Gracis Gerry. Así ha funcionado!

Comment: Me han surgido un par de preguntas más porfavor:

Comment: Gerry, gracias por tu solución anterior, pero se podría mejorar esa solución si en lugar de seleccionar del select, me cogiera directamente del contacto todos los datos? es decir, en mi lista de contactos tengo nombre, apellidos, etcc y show-edit-negociacion. Si le pulso a negociación, no sería mejor si me cogiera ya automáticamente todos los datos?

Comment: @user87071 ¿Cuál es la forma completa?, ¿quieres que se cambien los datos a partir de la selección del `select`?

Comment: Hola Gerry. No exactamente desde un select. Me explico: en contactos tengo mi lista de contactos:  nombre, apellidos, empresa... y al lado de cada contacto tengo show-edit-destroy-negociacion. Cuando pulso a negociacion me lleva al link de new negociacion y ahí tengo que poner manualmente el  nombre del contacto.En lugar de eso quisiera que cuando selecciono el "negociacion" de un contacto, que me me coja ya directamente el nombre del contacto en lugar de teclearlo a mano (para no tener que volver a contactos para ver como se llama). No se si me he explicado correctamente.Con form.input no fun

Comment: Hola Gerry. He conseguido hacer lo siguiente. Desde el link de Negociacions: <%= link_to 'Negociacions', new_negociacion_path(contacto.nombre),data:{confirm: 'Are you sure add negociacion por user: '<%=contacto.nombre%>? y al pulsar ok, entonces me muestra en la barra de navegación el nombre el usuario. Algo es algo. Ahora donde necesito que lo muestre es directamente en el campo correspondiente de new negociacion. Es donde no lo logro. Al igual que en la pregunta de Are you sure to add a negociacion por the user?:quiero que me muestre el nombre de usuario pero asi no sale <%=contacto.nombre%>

Comment: Disculpa Gerry que te vuelva a contactar. De las dos preguntas anteriores, la segunda la acabo de resolver asi: 'Do you want add a negociacion for the user: '+(contacto.nombre)+'?' y asi ya me coje el nombre. La primera pregunta lamentablemente no se como mostrar el nombre ...

Comment: @user87071 Creo que entiendo lo que buscas, ¿podrías abrir una pregunta nueva donde muestres el código que comentas? Así será más sencillo entender lo que buscas y podré darte una mejor respuesta (a través de comentarios es más complicado y poco útil para otros usuarios).

Comment: Si, gracias. Abro una pregunta nueva y espero que te llegue a ti :)